# Convert AD Date String Value to DateTime in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert Date VALUE retrieved from Active Directory to something readable.

I know external windows System32 application can be used:

`CMD - > w32tm.exe /ntte 128271382742968750` gives

`148462 05:57:54.2968750 - 6/24/2007 6:57:54 AM`

I tried:

```
Dim returnString as String = "128271382742968750"
Dim dta As DateTime = TimeValue(returnString)
```

That throws an exception.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: **Turn OPTION STRICT ON!**

Comment: What is TimeValue? Also, what exception?

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory stores these values as Windows file times, which you can convert using [`DateTime.FromFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletime?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Dim returnString as String = "128271382742968750"
Dim dta As DateTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(Long.Parse(returnString))
```

Result:

```
6/24/2007 5:57:54 AM
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/wH2Re0

Comment: That worked.Thanks. I tried earlier New Date(returnString) but that was returning some rubbish so I though the datetime value from AD is a different beast all together.

Comment: Consider just using a literal long (`Int64`) value like: `Dim dta As DateTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(128271382742968750L)`.  You might also want to consider `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`